# return 404 error on existing directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok so i have a directory in my root folder called */pages* in which i keep all my pages that i include thru index.php

What I wonder is would could i somehow return a 404 error if someone requests it? i dont like snoopy people...

Answer (score 8):

Is there any way you can re-structure your app so that those pages are **outside** the document root?  Much better answer...

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely put the data outside the web root as gahooa says.

If that's *totally* impossible due to provider restrictions, then put a .htaccess with the following contents into the directory:

```
deny from all
```

that should block all requests to files in that directory and return a "401 forbidden".

Answer (score 2):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^pages($|/) - [L,R=404]
```

But the `R=404` flag does only work since Apache 2.

Answer (score 1):

gahooa gives the best solution. If you can't place files outside of document root and your host runs Apache 1.3, you can also use [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
Redirect 404 /pages
```